# How to get statistics on MySQL query response sizes?

Tags: mysql

We have a database server and an application server talking to each other over TCP.  Recently, the data going between the servers has ballooned, and we have a situation where the database server has 10TB of outgoing data to the application server each month, and we can't find a good reason for this.  We've tried to find the problematic queries, but to no avail as they typically spike once in a day or two, not constantly.

I know MySQL has a slow query log, that shows queries that took a long time.  Is there a way to create a "big query log," where we'll see all queries that returned more than X bytes of data?

Comment: backup? or query without filter?

Comment: Backups are all local, so it wouldn't be that.  It's almost definitely what you say -- a single query with no filters (or incorrect filters) -- but because my framework (Django) builds queries for me, it's very hard to figure out where that query is hiding without this kind of log.